# Posting nested data in DjangoRestFramework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to post to a many to many field on a model.

The below code POSTS (gives a 200 OK response) but the data ("text") never gets posted.

I've used a PDB trace, and `info_data` does contain the right data.

FYI I had to use `self.initial` data as the `validate_data` was striping away the PK field.

Models.py:

```
class Info(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField("HTML/Text String", max_length=50000, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True)

class Movie(models.Model):
    info = models.ManyToManyField('Info', blank=True)
```

Serializer:

```
class InfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Info
        fields = ('text', 'pk')

class EditorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    info = InfoSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('info',)
    def update(self, instance, initial_data):
        infos_data = self.initial_data.pop('info')
        for info_data in infos_data:
            info_qs = Info.objects.filter(pk=info_data['pk'])
            if info_qs.exists():
                info = info_qs.first()
            else:
                info = Info.objects.create(**info_data)
            instance.info.add(info)
            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        return instance
```

Views.py

```
class EditorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EditorSerializer
```

The data I'm posting looks like this:

```
{"info":[{"text":"Test POST", "pk":2}]}
```

I'm posting it the the PK of the MOVIE model:

```
example.com/api/Editor/123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I needed import PK in the info serializer to save doing the `self.initial` work around.

I also basically firstly have to validate the data, I scoped it as `infos_data`.

I then had to check the Info class for the PK so I could update it. I called my content (text) then saved it.

```
class InfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=False, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Info
        fields = ('text', 'pk')

class EditorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    info = InfoSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('info',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        infos_data =  validated_data.pop('info')
        for info_data in infos_data:
            info = Info.objects.get(pk=info_data['pk'])
            info.text = info_data['text']
            info.save()
```